# Is there a way to keep receiving output in Jupyter code cell inadvertently converted to raw

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, nbconvert

I have a long running process (5+ days on remote server) in Jupyter that would output an update every few hours. I had a slip of the hand when moving my laptop and pressed the "r" key, thus converting the cell in question to Raw NBConvert and dumping all of the outputs.

I'm not as concerned about the lost output, but I do want to continue receiving future output. Converting the cell back to code was unsuccessful. 
I checked the notebook logs and it is still sending messages but they are not being displayed. Is there a way to retrieve these outputs?